# How to use foreach without knowing depth to simple array in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, foreach, tree

I have this big array  like as follows

```
 Array
    (
        [Prosess 1_35] => Array
            (
                [AF Decom_582] => Array
                    (
                        [documents] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [documents] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [title] => 
                                [doc_id] => 726

                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [title] => Brunvollquizen
                                [doc_id] => 878

                            )

                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [title] => Nytt dokument
                                [doc_id] => 1200

                            )

                        [3] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [title] => 
                                [doc_id] => 1215

                            )

                        [4] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [title] => Procedure AXC-12
                                [doc_id] => 1216

                            )

                    )

            )

        [Prosess 2_2] => Array
            (
                [documents] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [title] => 
                                [doc_id] => 1178

                            )

                    )

            )

        [Prosess 3_3] => Array
            (
                [Delprosess 3-1_10] => Array
                    (
                      [test1_340] => Array
                     (
                        [documents] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )
                        [documents] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [documents] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )
    )
```

I need to create one simple array like

Process 1_35 have 4 documents and one subfolder and subfolder don't have documents 
Process 2_2 have 1 document Process 3_3 no document but one subfolder'
and need to add one empty array after everyone folder

```
    array(
    array('Prosess 1_35',NULl,NUL...)
    array('NULL','doc_name,'doc_id')
    array('NULL','doc_name,'doc_id')
    array('NULL','doc_name,'doc_id')
    array('NULL','doc_name,'doc_id')
    array('  AF Decom_582',NULL,NULL)
    array('NULL','NULL',''NULL)
    array('Prosess 2_2',NULl,NUL...)
    array('NULL','doc_name,'doc_id')
    array('Prosess 3_3',NULl,NUL...)
    array('  Delprosess 3-1_10',NULl,NUL...)
    array('    test1_340',NULl,NUL...)

)
```

I tried below code but unfortunately, I am unable to make this as simple array

```
private static function _createArray1($requirementdocs, $level = 0)
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("&nbsp;", $level * 2);*/
        foreach($requirementdocs as $key => $sreq)
        {
            $rowarr = array();
                     $key = explode("_",$subkey);
                $rowarr[0] = $indent.$key[1];
            if ($key[0] == "documents" && !empty($sreq)) continue;
            foreach($sreq as $subkey => $req)
            {

                $rowarr[1] = $req->doc_id;
                $rowarr[2] = $req->title;
                array_push($res , $rowarr);
            }

            self::_createArray($sreq, $level+1);
        }

    }
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Use recursion method

Comment: already using it in my code

Comment: No, you are not, the method does not call itself, but a different method, meaning, `_createArray1` should call `_createArray1` **not** `_createArray`

Comment: Also, you're not returning anything from the "recursive method" either, so the result will not be pased through.

Comment: This is just sample code but in actual code I am returning

Comment: Gah! Seriously, if you want us to help you with your code, **show us your code**! How are we suppose to find eventual bugs or issues if you just present invalid pseudo code?! This drives me NUTS!

Comment: I hv updated the code

Answer (score 1):

Is this, what you want to accomplish?

```
$arr = [
    [
        [
            1
        ],
        [
            1
        ],
        [
            1
        ],
    ],
    [
        1
    ],
    [
        [
            1
        ],
        [
            [
                [
                    1
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ]
];

echo '<pre>'; print_r($arr); echo '</pre>';

$new = flatten($arr);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($new); echo '</pre>';
```

And the recursive method:

```
function flatten($array, $depth = INF)
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $item = $item instanceof Collection ? $item->all() : $item;

        if (is_array($item)) {
            if ($depth === 1) {
                $result = array_merge($result, $item);
                continue;
            }

            $result = array_merge($result, flatten($item, $depth - 1));
            continue;
        }

        $result[] = $item;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Btw, this is the Laravel helper [array_flatten](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-array-flatten) method code.